# how to get min and max value from Array of Model class excluding zero

Tags: java, android

```
[{
    "function": "Weight",
    "details": [{
            "date": "2017-07-24T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-07-25T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-07-26T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 30         },
        {
            "date": "2017-07-27T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 45
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-07-28T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 52
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-07-29T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 0
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 0
        }
    ]
   }]
```

This is my josn data i want  to get mine and max value in such manner it exclude 0 value from array in given array of object expected output should min : 30 and max 52 i am trying below code for get max and min value :

```
public class VitalCompare implements Comparator<VitalReportsDetails> {
    @Override
    public int compare(VitalReportsDetails vitalReportsDetails, VitalReportsDetails t1) {
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt((vitalReportsDetails.getValue().equals("") ? "0" : vitalReportsDetails.getValue()));

        int n2 = Integer.parseInt((t1.getValue().equals("")? "0" : t1.getValue()));
        if (n1 >= n2 ) {
            return 1;
        }
        return -1;

    }

}
```

and calling like this :

```
String minValue = Collections.min(hm.get("Weight"), new VitalCompare()).getValue();
                int min = (minValue.equals("0") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(minValue));
                customViewHolder.highlabel_text.setText(Integer.parseInt(Collections.max(hm.get("Weight"), new VitalCompare()).getValue()) + "Kg High | " + min + "Kg Low");
```

but each time i am getting 0 min value please suggest me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Probably stupid suggestion. But the min value of data you've shown is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the invalid data *before* computing your aggregates:

```
ArrayList<VitalReportsDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();
for(VitalReportsDetails detail : hm.get("Weight")) {
    if(!detail.getValue().equals("0")) { details.add(detail); }
}

int min, max;
if(details.isEmpty()) {
    // No data => default values
    min = 0;
    max = 0;
} else {
    min = Integer.parseInt(Collections.min(details, new VitalCompare()).getValue());
    max = Integer.parseInt(Collections.max(details, new VitalCompare()).getValue());
}
```

You can probably also make "value" an int directly when parsing your JSON to avoid all the String-to-int conversions.

Comment: error is coming when i use removeIf method @CodeConfident

Comment: @Adevelopment - Sorry, I think it was added in Java 8. I thought it was on ArrayList prior to that. I'll update it for Android.

Comment: @Adevelopment - Updated. Not quite as pretty, but should work with Java 7.

Comment: Thankyou very much

Comment: @Code-confident Hi if there is no data means every value 0 then this code fails showing null pointer exception how i will handle  i want set  0 place  blank data

Comment: I guess the cleanest is to check the list size before computing: `if(details.isEmpty()) { // min/max are 0 } else { // Collections.min/max }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151880/discussion-between-adevelopment-and-codeconfident).